# Understanding Modulus Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm looking for a short text or primer (maybe max 20-30 pages) which explains the basics of modulus arithmetic and how it apply to rings. Specifically, I'm looking for a text that explains how the maps $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/p^{m}\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$,and $\mathbb{Z}/p^{m-n}\mathbb{Z} \to p^{n}\mathbb{Z}/p^{m}\mathbb{Z}$ $(m \ge n$) "work". I'm just very shaky when working in modulus arithmetic...

Comment: I have a book with a section of that topic explained in elementary form. The only problem is that it is in Spanish. Serves you?

Comment: I do not speak or read Spanish...

Answer (score 1):

As I recall Joseph Silverman's *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* has a pretty good chapter on modular arithmetic...

Also you could look up the relevant sections in Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*...  for more on the rings (and mappings, i suspect) you mentioned...

Modular arithmetic is fundamental in both subjects, and while I don't know of any short primer, the chapter in Silverman should be around $10-20$ pages, for instance...

I highly recommend both books...

Comment: Does there happy to be a PDF of Silverman's book anywhere? I couldn't find one after some simple google searching.

Comment: For the first book look [here](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html), and for the second check it out [here](http://www.vgloop.com/f-/1422977427-302599.pdf).